# OnCollisionEnter is not being called when it should be

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My script is not working despite being able to compile. When the gameobject collides with a gameobject with the name "Coin", it should `Debug.log("my message")` in the console, but no message is logged implying no collision occurs with a coin. It will not function even when I drag it onto the gameobject. Please help. 
Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyCoin : MonoBehaviour
{  
    //Detect collisions between the GameObjects with Colliders attached
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Coin") { 
            Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug this?

Comment: Try `Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name)` and figure out what we are hitting to make sure we're using the right name. Then make sure both objects have a `collider` component and that this script is attached to the `GO` that is colliding with the coin. In the event it's actually printing, make sure the console option to show messages is enabled.

Comment: As far as I remember bodies need to have the RigidBody component + they need to be dynamic and not kinematic. Try that if see if it works.

Comment: Still didn't work unfortunately @TheLazyScripter by GO you mean the object that is colliding with the coin right?

Comment: @AmN Both already dynamic.

Comment: Is it detecting any type collision? Try removing the if () condition and just print something there.

Comment: Is the Unity in play mode?

Comment: @AmN What does this exactly mean? And Hasan Emrah Sungu, yes it is.

Comment: What I mean is this: `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
            Debug.Log("Collision Detected"); 
    }`

See if this prints anything.

Comment: @AmN It did not print anything.

Comment: Are you using 2D colliders?

Comment: I would do what @AmN suggested and remove the if statement around the Debug.Log call. From there you should just try and get a collision with any object and print the name to verify collisions are occuring.

Comment: Also here is a link to the manual page for collisions. It has a table at the bottom that you can use to verify when collisions occur. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: Does any of your rigidbodies that are supposed to be colliding is kinematic? Collisions won't work then. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: Make sure both gameobjects have a collider and that the collider isn't set to trigger. Also check if the name "Coin" is correct, I would assume you would have more Coin objects in game therefore it's better to set up a tag and compare that.

Comment: @MitjaPolner Both have a collider, both dynamic, is not set to trigger, Coin is correct, the tag is also Coin. And I only have on coin in the game right now. I'm just grabbing the bare bone's of game development in unity. And I already compared tag did not work.

Comment: "On collision enter" Does this mean i have to enter the collider or something

Comment: OnCollisionEnter is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider. Is your script attached to the correct gameObject?

Comment: Could you provide some screen shots of your objects in the inspector so we can see the configuration and what components they have?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0LGcy23 @Arc2066

Comment: @Arc2066 https://imgur.com/a/q5fOp9m (player)

Comment: @MitjaPolner I've tried both with the script attached and both individuality.

Comment: @ChilledWolf If you're using 2D colliders and physics you should use OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, had to change some thing's attach script to coin (I will show new script in a second.) Add a regular collider to the coin. Add a trigger collider to it also. And this is the following code!

'using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyCoin : MonoBehaviour
{

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
    }
}
```

} < Add this into the script at the very end.

Thank you ALL for trying to help me and sticking with me through this long process. You have all led me to this idea. <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "OnCollisionEnter2D".